IDA: Invalid Operand when use 64bit instead of 32bit
I use IDA to modify the .exe of a game. I found the section where a limitation of 999.999.999 is given, but I'd like to change to higher limit at best to a 64bit value. My issue is that IDA returns Invalid Operand when I try to Patch Programm -> Assemble from eax to rax and 3B9AC9FFh to 1111222233334444h. What would be a good approach to solve this problem?
Assembler code:
mov     eax, 3B9AC9FFh // eax=999.999.999
cmp     r12, rax       // r12-999.999.999, then set flags
cmovg   r12, rax       // limit r12 by 999.999.999 and handle negative + overflow, according to flags


So this compares r12 to the limit and if it is greater, sets r12 to the limit? And you want there to be no limit? Have you considered what the nop instruction can do for you?

Yes, I came up with that idea, but I was unsure what happens in case of negative + overflow, if r12 is negative and r12-rax cause overflow?

The only way to do that results in r12 being not negative anymore after the overflow (SF is based on whether the result of the subtraction is negative, not whether the input is negative), in other words nothing happens. But you're looking at this the hard way. cmovg is named such because (when combined with a comparison) it implement "conditional move if greater-than" ie perform the move if r12 > rax (with signed-greater-than)

What do you want to happen if r12 is negative? Unconditionally zeroing the sign bit is something that can be done in 12 bytes. (this would wrap it around to some smallish positive value)

Oh yeah, got confused after becoming familiar with cmovg and read about SF=OF=1-case. What is that case for then, r12<rax and ...? Do I get it right, that replacing eax with rax would change size needed for instruction, therefore the reason I get Invalid Operand? The r12 to be negative was my thought about that case, but I was wrong, just didn't want to break the game :)

Well, mov rax, 1111222233334444h would be 10 bytes, vs 5 for mov eax, 3B9AC9FFh. But IDK what IDA is up to, mov rax, 1111222233334444h doesn't have an invalid operand so it's an unfortunate error message

From my knowledge IDA is not able to handle larger instruction, it would break the .exe, because everything would have to be shifted, i.e. jmp loc_1407CBC7F. But I still wonder what SF=OF=1 would be, is that an underflow (r12-rax<0 unsigned), which is impossible as long as rax is a signed value, saying its first bit is and interpreted as sign flag? If so, using nop will cause no issues.

@user555045: consider 8-bit for easier thought experiments.  cmp or sub with operands 42 and -128 will compute 42 - (-128) which wraps to -86 since 170 doesn't fit.  (With OF=1 since there was signed overflow and SF=1 since the 8-bit result has its MSB set).  Thus the g (signed-greater) condition is true because 42 > -128.  If a subtraction overflowed, the sign bit will be opposite of the mathematically correct result, which is why signed compare conditions involve OF.  SF == OF is a compact way to express "SF unless OF, otherwise opposite of SF".

If IDA requires the replacement instruction to fit in the same number of bytes as what it's replacing, there's your answer. 64-bit operand-size requires a REX prefix, and a constant that doesn't fit in a sign-extended 32-bit immediate requires another 4 extra bytes.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov / Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64)

@user555045: Oops, yeah I meant to reply to the OP, sorry for the noise.
